# Image with caption -- how to strech and center it?

Tags: html, css, image, center

When I had just an image I had a nice working solution -- I could center (in both axis) an image and also stretch it in such way, that it was no bigger than container and no smaller (it preserved the ratio).

Now I would like to add a caption directly under the image in such way, that caption takes the space based on font size, and the image stretch to what is left from the container space. And I am unable to do it.

My previous solution (I left constraint only on height) -- now, not working:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid;box-sizing: border-box; width: 1000px; padding: 8px; height: 200px; text-align: center; " >
    <span style="display: inline-block; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle;"></span>
    <img style="display:inline-block; max-height:100%; " src="icons/speaking.png" ></img>
    <br/><span style="">TEST</span>
</div>
```

Other tries, but they work even worse, image is no stretched in any way. `table` with `table-cell`

```
<div style="border: 1px solid;box-sizing: border-box; width: 1000px; padding: 8px; height: 200px; text-align: center; " >
    <div style="display:table;width:100%;height:100%;max-height:100%;">
        <div style="vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell;max-height:100%;">
            <img style="display:inline;max-height:100%;" src="icons/speaking.png" ></img>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or `figure` -- no difference really:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid;box-sizing: border-box; width: 1000px; padding: 8px; height: 200px; text-align: center; " >
    <div style="display:table;width:100%;height:100%;max-height:100%;">
        <figure style="vertical-align:middle;display:table-cell;max-height:100%;">
            <img style="max-height:100%" src="icons/speaking.png" ></img>
            <figcaption style="">TEST</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

**IMPORTANT:** I don't have a working solution, any solution, but I try to solve this problem without any fixed values except for container. The reason for this is, then when resize occurs, I have set the dimension of the container, and the content scale accordingly.

Big container, the image occupies almost entire height, it cannot fit width to 100%, because the height would be too big (odd look may be the result of my Gimp skills):

[image: Container is bigger]

Small container, the image is squeezed. Still there is room for text preserved.

[image: Image is smaller]

The text may look like scaled up (by comparison), but the size of it is the same -- only the image is squeezed, and container is smaller.

Comment: How about setting `position:absolute` on the caption?

Comment: @Danield, no problem, but how it solves the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the browsers you want to support allow you to use flexbox, I think you can achieve it in the following fashion. Instead of using a `<img>` tag for the image I've opted to use a `background-image` together with `background-position: center center` and `background-size: contain` to center and stretch the image. It might be worthwhile to see if you can implement this using a `<img>` tag.

I've added `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` on the container `.media` class. If you add `flex-grow: 1` on the `.media__image` class this will make the image container grow until the entire height is used.

```css
.media {  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.media__image {
  flex-grow: 1;
  
  background: url('http://placehold.it/150x100') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: #f99;
}
.media__caption {
  background-color: #9f9;  
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
  <div class="media__image"></div>
  <div class="media__caption">
    Caption
  </div>
</div>
```

See this <kbd>**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/ZYOwZW?editors=110)**</kbd> for three examples using different sized containers, images and fonts.

For background information on using flexbox:

- [CSS-Tricks complete guide to Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [Browser support at caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)
- [Flexbox cheatsheet](http://jonibologna.com/flexbox-cheatsheet/)
- [A tool to play with flexbox](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am reading and trying to understand all the goodies you posted, and also fixing one remaining issue -- when you set the container with big height (let's say as twice as the height of the image), the caption lands at the bottom of the container, not below (directly below) the image.

Comment: That might prove to be a bit harder I fear. Currently the `flex-grow: 1` makes the `.media__image` take what's left in the `.media` container after adding the caption. I had trouble trying to get a regular `<img>` tag to stretch/shrink in the vertical direction if it's height constrained. I guess if I figure that out I can get it to work without using flexbox. Am I correct in assuming that it should stetch small images and shrink large images to fit in a width and height constrained container?

Comment: Yes, indeed. However keeping the ratio, so naive approach with directly adding `img` into flexbox does not work (I already checked). This is what you have already achieved :-)

Comment: I was playing around with a `<img>` tag (see http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/KwMYpX) it however doesn't stretch the image (only shrinks) plus it needs a height on both the `.image` container and the `img`. I'm getting afraid it can't be done as you want the height of the image to be constrained by the caption height and at the same time have the image height influence the height of the caption.

Comment: Thank you. If you say so, I am accepting your answer, because it is super useful, very close to what I asked for. Maybe I will find the answer :-) Thank you very, very much.

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for accepting! I'm not 100% certain though, and do check if you need to support old versions of Internet Explorer as they don't support flexbox

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you want to set a specific font size to the caption and the image re-size itself to the same width of the caption, maintaining it's aspect ration.

In this case I suggest you to use table a table with two TR and one TD. Put image in first row (TR) and the caption in the second row. Do not define the width of the TABLE, TD or TD. So whatever font size you will give to the caption in the second row, the column will set its width to that size and the image with 100% width will set itself according to the TD size.

For example,

```html
<Table>
<TR>
   <img style="display:inline-block; max-height:100%; " src="icons/speaking.png" ></img>
   <TD></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
   <TD>
      <br/><span style="">TEST</span>
   </TD>
</TR>
<Table>
```

Comment: Thank you. It does not work now (content is not centered in any way, and the image is not stretched), but I will explore this approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am really confused..

Just by adding a simple html tag I have achieved what I think you're talking about how ever your question is very unclear.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
span {
font-size: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center><img src="http://i.imgur.com/S2E4MDu.png"/>
<br/><span style="">TEST</span></center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This centers the content and the span for me so all that's left to do is add a style in css for span declaring it to the size that you're looking for..

**EDIT:** I see that you are also having issues with it inside of a container so I went ahead and tested this as well.

```
.container {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid red;
}
.container img {
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
}
```

Simply wrap the container around the image

```
<div class="container">
<center><img src="http://i.imgur.com/S2E4MDu.png"/>
<br/><span style="">TEST</span></center>
</div>
```

And we should be set.

Comment: Thank you, but it is other way -- the size is set for container, and the image has to stretch, while in your approach you set the size for the image and the container is stretched. See the updated question.